# Can't convert an iterator of tuple to an iterator of strings

Tags: python-3.x, iterator

I'm trying to convert an iterator of tuples to an iterator of strings.
I must use itertools, so I'm not allowed to use either for or while.

```
import itertools
def parlar_lloro(it0):
    it1 = filter(lambda x: len(x)>=5, it0)
    it2 = map(lambda x: x[:len(x)-2], it1)
    it3, it4 = itertools.tee(it2, 2)
    n = len(list(it3))
    itn = itertools.repeat('CROA', n)
    ite = zip(it4, itn)
    return itr
```

What I get when executing this on Python's Shell is:

```
>>> [(abc,'CROA'),(def,'CROA'),(ghi,'CROA')]
```

And I want:

```
>>> ['abc','CROA','def','CROA','ghi','CROA']
```

Comment: Could you provide the sample input you have and a description of what the task is - your code isn't the easiest to follow.

Comment: If I'm reading correctly - take everything 5 or more characters, remove the last two characters, then interweave it with the text "CROA" ?

Comment: Yes, the input they give me is an iterator of random words that coud have more than 5 characters or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're suppose to be using `itertools` then I suspect what you're expected to use is `itertools.chain`...

Change your return to be (I'm guessing `itr` is a typo and you meant `ite`):

```
return itertools.chain.from_iterable(ite)
```

Just for reference, the same thing can be accomplished using a list-comp:

```
res = [sub for el in ((it[:-2], 'CROA') for it in x if len(it) >= 5) for sub in el]
```

Comment: Right, I missclicked r instead of e. Can you explain why you used itertools.chain.from_iterable? Does itertools.chain.from_iterable convert a list of tuples into a list of str?

Comment: About the way you reduce the code, I'm not at that level as I'm a first-year-student of Industrial Engineering and I don't understand a thing of what you did :) But is good to see other ways of coding the same thing!!